# Validation Rule to allow numbers and blank spaces only, not longer than 20 characters

Tags: community, validation, regular-expressions

I have created following validation rule, but struggling how to add to it to also allow blank (space) values.

```
AND(NOT(ISBLANK(field__c)),
OR( LEN(field__c) > 20, NOT(REGEX(field__c,"^[0-9]+$"))))
```

Comment: By blank I mean space

Comment: `REGEX(field__c,"^[0-9\s]+$")`

Comment: I'd replace the whole validation rule with `NOT(REGEX(field__c,"^[0-9\s]{1,20}$"))`

Comment: Assuming `field__c` is a text field, you could enforce the field length restriction through the field metadata itself. Also, I can't recall if Salesforce auto-trims leading/trailing whitespace in text fields, but if they do then having only whitespace wouldn't be possible. Even if it is though, how would that be any different than allowing the field to be blank in the first place? Going into more detail about why you're implementing this validation rule (what business issue does this help you/your org solve?) may be more productive.

Comment: Yes field is text field and displayed on community page for customer to submit their ref number, but often customers put space at the end or at the front so we want to allow them to submit it if there is one, we also want to allow to submit if they do not have it at hand.  Regards length, we have this restriction on the field already, BUT it does not fire error message on community page, so customers by pass it and we receive failed cases.

Comment: Yep, a quick check confirmed that Salesforce does trim out leading and trailing whitespace in text fields.

Comment: I'm not sure if being on a community page has any effect here, or if auto-trimming explains the lack of error message. At any rate though, that's the kind of detail that you should include in your questions. Perhaps [the official help on Assigning Error Pages for Community sites](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sites_error_pages.htm&type=5) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I'd opt to do this through configuring the field rather than through a validation rule.

Given that this is a `Text` type field (and not a `TextArea`, `TextArea (Long)`, or `TextArea (Rich)`), you can define the max length as part of the field itself.

That'll give you an automatic error message (which I assume Salesforce has already translated/localized for other locales, if that's a concern) which is slightly less terrifying for users. Users' minds shut down at pretty much any error, but something like

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0013m0000383mtzAAA; first error: STRING_TOO_LONG, SLA Serial Number: data value too large: 1234567890123 (max length=11):

is better (in my opinion) than what you'd get with a validation rule

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0013m0000383mtzAAA; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, 10 chars or fewer: [SLASerialNumber__c]

Specifically, the actual error "String too long" appears sooner and is in all caps. I believe we're conditioned to pay more attention to all-caps things as well, so `STRING_TOO_LONG` is better than `FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION`

You also say that you want to allow people to submit data without needing to supply this ref number. So that means you can't have any validation rule that has an `ISBLANK(field__c)` on its own.

### Whitespace handling

Salesforce auto-trims leading and trailing whitespace from text fields. This is done before system validation (i.e. defining the max length as part of the field itself) and validation rules are run. So there is no need to handle the scenario where people are including whitespace before/after the ref number.

If you get a reference number that's length 20, and you get 100 whitespace after it, it'll get trimmed down to a length of 20 before you/Salesforce have a chance to object.

If the field contains *only* whitespace, then it all gets trimmed out and you end up with a blank text field (i.e. the value is `null`)

### About the only scenario where a Validation Rule makes sense here

Is if you want to ensure that this reference number is populated *eventually*.

Say, if this is generating a `Case` in Salesforce, and you want to make sure the ref number is populated before the Case's `Status` is "Closed".

Beyond that, a validation rule doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: Thank you Derek :) When you get caught up in requirements so good to have fresh pair of eyes :)  did not think about triming at all :)